# Protractor Promise Never Resolved During Debugging

Tags: protractor

I've started my Protractor debugging session with:   node --inspect-brk

When I hit a break point I want to be able to manually execute some Protractor commands.  However my promises are never resolved.  For example if I enter this into the Chrome console:

```
$('body').isDisplayed().then((displayed) => {console.log('here i am'});
```

However all I get returned back is "Promise is Pending" and the promise is never resolved.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use async / await. If you are not using async / await, then this means you are still on the control flow and node --inspect-brk will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I got round this with control flow by attaching a breakpoint to the code i want to jump to, in this case the console.log and continuing to it

Answer (score 0):

you are not actually resolving the promise, and don't need the argument either. Try this:

```
$('body').isDisplayed()
    .then(function(){
        return console.log('here i am');
    });
```